# How can I assign value for ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to specific the legend order in my ggplot, and the legend order indeed changed as I expected. However, when I assigned value for the plot, the result of legend is not as I expected. My code is

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-data.frame(time=c(1:10),y=c(150000,100000,50000,rep(70000,7)),IC=c("150000","100000","50000",rep("1",7)))
ggplot(data,aes(x=time,y=y))+
geom_line()+
geom_point(data=data[data$IC=="100000",],aes(col=IC,shape=IC),size=5)+
geom_point(data=data[data$IC=="150000",],aes(col=IC,shape=IC),size=5)+
geom_point(data=data[data$IC=="50000",],aes(col=IC,shape=IC),size=5)+
scale_colour_manual(name = "points",
                  breaks =c("50000", "100000", "150000"),
                  values = c("green", "blue", "red"))+
scale_shape_manual(name = "points",
                 breaks =c("50000", "100000", "150000"),
                 values = c(1,2,3))+theme_bw()
```

[image]

What I expected is that the point of (50000,100000,150000) can be expressed as (green,blue,red) ans also the shape is (circle, cross,triangle). But it seems the values are still assigned as its default order. How can I solve it?

Comment: tried scale_color_identity ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` will assign legend order in the exact same order of your factor variable "IC" which is:

```r
> levels(data$IC)
[1] "1"      "100000" "150000" "50000"
```

Modifying breaks will only change the order they are display on the legend but not the color or shape assigned.

One possible solution to change this order is to reorder levels of your factor variable "IC" before passing the dataset into `ggplot2`:

```r
data$IC <- factor(data$IC, levels = c("1","50000","100000","150000"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,aes(x=time,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data = subset(data, IC != "1"), aes(color = IC, shape = IC), size = 5)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "points",
                      values = c("green", "blue", "red"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "points",
                     values = c(1,2,3))+theme_bw()
```

[image]

An another option is to directly pass the assignement of color and shape of each values directly into `scale_color_manual` and `scale_shape_manual` such as:

```r
ggplot(data,aes(x=time,y=y))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(data = subset(data, IC != "1"), aes(color = IC, shape = IC), size = 5)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "points",
                      breaks =c("50000", "100000", "150000"),
                      values = c("50000" = "green", "100000" = "blue", "150000" = "red"))+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "points",
                     breaks =c("50000", "100000", "150000"),
                     values = c("50000" = 1, "100000" = 1, "150000" = 3))+theme_bw()
```